# What are pro's and cons of cookies versus sessions?

Tags: html, session, cookies

Can someone give me some good reading material on what's best in different cases?

I guess when you have a small website with not a lot of users, you could go for sessions since they are stored on a server. But for a bigger amount of users it may be better to go with cookies? And how do they both score on safety?

Comment: One thing to bear in mind if you are working on sites in the EU or for sites hosted outside of the EU but for EU based companies is that on the 26th of May this year the new cookies legislation comes into force which will mean that we cannot store data in cookies without the users consent.

Comment: So this means adding a line in the terms & condition that says 'we will store a cookie on your computer in order for you to login' ?

Comment: It is also worth bearing in mind that, despite people shouting about "cookie law" it doesn't let you use other methods to track users either (and a session tracked via a cookie (as 99%+ are) uses cookies). Also, if the cookie is required for essential functionality then you don't need permission (e.g. they add their first item to their shopping basket, you can start a session and set a cookie to track the session).

Comment: @Vincent — No. Permission must be explicit, not hidden away in a T&C that nobody reads. IANAL.

Answer (score 6):

Session management is divided into two methodologies -- server side and client side. The use of cookies places trust on the client side, as well as the physical state management portion of your application. Not all browsers support cookies, and users have the option to either enable to disable cookies based on their discretion. This places a unique road block in the face of many developers, as they cannot be entirely dependent on the clients system to ensure that they are actively accepting cookies. Clients can kill active cookies at any time. The upside to using cookies is that it is managed by the client, and can live on the client system, being used to track visits to your site and other data that needs to be persisted for long periods of time.

Sessions on the other hand are server side technology. They are actively managed by the server, and their state lives and dies with the server respectively. They are a good way to ensure, regardless of the client system, that the developer is able to maintain some sort of state across browsers. Sessions can be more complex in nature due to concepts such as web farms, but can be overcome by choosing the appropriate type of session state management and storage. The downsides to using sessions are that they are usually short lived and are created to manage a unique visit to your site, without persisting over long periods of time.

Answer (score 3):

Sessions almost always use cookies to associate the session with a user (although it is possible to pass strings in the query string or form data with every request).

Cookies:

- Have to be included in every HTTP request
- Have limits on the amount of data you can store
- Expose the data you store to the user (and anyone who can sniff their traffic if you don't use SSL)
- Allow users to edit the data directly
- Can be set to persist for some time

Sessions don't.

> But for a bigger amount of users it may be better to go with cookies?

If you are storing *that* much data, then you either have a tiny, tiny hard disk or you are going to exceed the cookie size limits … so no.

Comment: There are pros for cookies though.  Cookies persist for a preset, known amount of time, while sessions don't. Cookies persist between connections, sessions don't.

Comment: A number of the things I listed above (including mention of the persistence) are not "cons", just reality. They may be desirable or undesirable features depending on the context.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use them in different situations, because both have pros and cons.
The biggest con of sessions is that a session is often destroyed when the browser is closed. Cookies on the other hand don't get destroyed that easy.
Cookies aren't always supported while sessions almost always are.

They are both not safe. And as far as I know cookies use slightly more performance. A safer (safer not safe) way to store data on the client side, is by verifying the session information to a hash saved in the database. Store a session ID with the hash in the database. And look it up. next time. If you really want to be secure. Use a token, and generate a new one everytime the information is looked up.

So I'd have to make such a decision. If the information has to be stored for multiple browser sessions. use cookies. But if you just have to save the information for a couple of pageswitches, just use sessions.

Edit: So okay I ran it over my apache server and tracked RAM and CPU activity. (No significant results) Also I checked the time it took the server to set and unset 1000 variables (containing 30 character long string) into sessions and Cookies. Did all tests a couple times and took the avg. result. Here are the results.

```
COOKIES
  Set: 0.001863 seconds.
  Unset: 0.004932 seconds.

SESSIONS:
  Set: 0.000494 seconds. (very consistent results)
  Unset: 0.000502 seconds. (Again very consistent)
```

So sessions are quite a lot faster and way more consistent. If you're able to use sessions. I'd definitely go for sessions.

Comment: No read necessary, saving data on the client side is never safe. You can make it safer by checking hashes on the server side but data manipulation is always possible.

Comment: Yes but then where you store the hashes to compare with the hashes from the session/cookiedata?

Comment: Store them into a database on the server side. and match the sessionid to the info in the database to verify a cookie/session. I'll add this to the answer.